# Can't Add Foreign Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have two tables naming 'customers' having 'productid' as primary key

```
 CustomerID | CustomerName | ContactName | Address  | PostalCode | Country | ProductID
------------+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------
          1 | John         | Jones       | Payson   | 34213      | Germany |         2
          2 | Mary         | Edward      | Sandiego | 43561      | Mexico  |        34
          3 | Eric         | Howell      | Phoenix  | 50023      | Mexico  |        11
          4 | Gus          | Gray        | Tucson   | 50021      | USA     |        54
          5 | Erica        | Williams    | Payson   | 76983      | UK      |        67
          6 | Elroy        | Cleaver     | Baghdad  | 34721      | France  |        55
```

and 'products' having 'unit' as primary key

```
 ProductID | ProductName   | SupplierID | CategoryID | Unit              |Price| Date
-----------+---------------------------+------------+------------+----------------------+--
         1 | Chais         |          1 |          1 | 10 boxesx20 bags  | 18  | 2008-11-11
         2 | Chang         |          1 |          1 | 24-12 oz bottles  | 19  | 2008-11-09
         3 | Aniseed Syrup |          1 |          2 | 12-550 ml bottles | 10  | 2008-05-12
        15 | Genen Shouyu  |          6 |          2 | 24-250 ml bottles | 15  | 2008-06-23
        16 | Pavlova       |          7 |          3 | 32-500 g boxes    | 17  | 2007-12-30
        21 | Sir Rodney's  |          8 |          3 | 24 pkgs.x4 pieces | 10  | 2007-01-09
        25 | NuNuCa Nuß    |         11 |          3 | 20 - 450 g glasses| 14  | 2007-05-04
        36 | Inlagd Sill   |         17 |         18 | 24 - 250 g jars   | 19  | 2007-02-09
```

using the following code to make productid in products table as foreign key

```
alter table products add constraint ck foreign key(productid) references customers(productid);
```

but the above code ends stating

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`products`.`#sql-6e0_2`, CONSTRAINT `ck` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFEREN
>   CES `customers` (`ProductID`))"

Comment: Are both tables InnoDB type?

Comment: There's no need to shout. [ Title edited. ]

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the key to the wrong table. You want to make `customers.ProductID` a foreign key to `products.ProductID`

```
ALTER TABLE `customers`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ck`
FOREIGN KEY(`ProductID`) REFERENCES `products` (`ProcuctID`)
```

The reason it's failing is because you have IDs in `product.ProductID` that are not present in `customers.ProductID` therefore, the constraint fails.